# Getting "selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, staleelementreferenceexception

Searching "Selenium" word in google, and i want to select a website whose link is in 2nd page . And when automation starts as per the condition it check it in first page since the condition is not satisfied its going to the second page and at that point i am getting "selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document". I know that the element in the DOM is not present in the second page.But i am unable to solve this exception.Please help me with this.`enter code here`. I have attached the screenshot of my code.
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMoNC.png)